# Code not showing output to button in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

Below is my code that I have had much help on from other users on this platform. I have tried running it and everything runs great, except the bottom button that says "Time Travel here!" prompts the user for an input, but does not show the answer at the top like the other button does.

I am also going to add years all the way until 1920, but I want to make sure it runs before I continue. Thank you!

Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:SandyBrown;">
    <script src="script.js">

    </script>
    <div id="question"></div>
    <h1 style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">Oh what a year that was!<h1>
            <p style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">If you are seeing this in the year 2020, you know
                what we all went through this year. There was everything from a gloabl pandemic, forest fires, presidental elections,
                everything. We all likely faced individual struggles as well. But do you were wish you could see what another year was
                like?
                <br>
          <br>
          <br>
      
          Let's take a blast to the past</p>
        <button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qone()">Question</button>
     <script >
       function qone() {
 var text;
 var year = prompt("How was your 2020?");
 switch(year) {
  case "Great":
    text = "That makes one of us...";
    break;
  case "Bad":
    text = "That makes two of us...";
    break;
  case "No comment":
    text = "Understood";
    break;
  default:
    text = "I Understand";
  }
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
}
     </script>
        
<br>
<br>
<form style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">

<label for=“year”>What year do you want to go to? You can go back anywhere from 1 to 100 years ago!</label>
<br>

<body>

<div id="qtwo"></div>

<button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qtwo()"; return false>Time Travel here!</button>

<script>
  function qtwo(){
    var text = "";
    var numyrs = prompt("What year would you like to go back to?");
    console.log(numyrs);
switch(numyrs) {
  case 2019:
  alert("Scientists release first-ever image of black hole.");
  break;
  case 2018:
  alert("The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal.");
  break;
  case 2017:
  alert("America had the first total solar eclipse in 99 years");
  break;
  case 2016:
  alert("Donald Trump was elected president of the United States");
  break;
  case 2015:
  alert("The U.S. Women Soccer Team wins the World Cup");
  break;
  case 2014:
  alert("The Seattle Seahawks beat the Denver Broncos, 43-8, to win their first Super Bowl in franchise history");
  break;
  case 2013:
  alert("The movie Iron Man 3 came out");
  break;
  case 2012:
  alert("The Miami Heat win their second NBA championship in franchise history");
  break;
  case 2011:
  alert("U.S. troops and CIA operatives shoot and terrorist kill Osama bin Laden in Pakistan");
  break;
  case 2010:
  alert("The United States finds more than $1 trillion in mineral resources in the mountains of Afghanistan");


  default:
  text = "";
  break;
  
document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = text;
  }
  }
</script>

<script src="script.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have two `<body>` tags - this is incorrect. Wrap everything in one `<body>` tag.

Comment: I just fixed this, thank you. However the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

1. You repeatedly say `alert(<message>)` when you meant to say `text = <message>`
2. The page is redirecting because of your `<form>` tag, so you need to add `onsubmit="(e) => e.preventDefault()"` to stop redirecting
3. You need to use `parseInt()` to convert the string that is returned from `prompt()` to an integer.
4. You used `document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML`, which I changed to `document.getElementById("question").innerText`. The id `"question"` needs to be lowercase, and since you're only adding text, you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` to make it clearer.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:SandyBrown;">
    <script src="script.js">

    </script>
    <div id="question"></div>
    <h1 style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">Oh what a year that was!<h1>
            <p style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">If you are seeing this in the year 2020, you know
                what we all went through this year. There was everything from a gloabl pandemic, forest fires, presidental elections,
                everything. We all likely faced individual struggles as well. But do you were wish you could see what another year was
                like?
                <br>
          <br>
          <br>
      
          Let's take a blast to the past</p>
        <button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qone()">Question</button>
     <script >
       function qone() {
 var text;
 var year = prompt("How was your 2020?");
 switch(year) {
  case "Great":
    text = "That makes one of us...";
    break;
  case "Bad":
    text = "That makes two of us...";
    break;
  case "No comment":
    text = "Understood";
    break;
  default:
    text = "I Understand";
  }
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
}
     </script>
        
<br>
<br>
<form style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;" onsubmit="(e) => e.preventDefault()">

<label for=“year”>What year do you want to go to? You can go back anywhere from 1 to 100 years ago!</label>
<br>


<div id="qtwo"></div>

<button style="text-align:center" onclick="qtwo()">Time Travel here!</button>

<script>
  function qtwo(){
    var text = "";
    var numyrs = parseInt(prompt("What year would you like to go back to?"));
    console.log(numyrs);
    debugger;
switch(numyrs) {
  case 2019:
  text = "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole.";
  break;
  case 2018:
  text = "The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal.";
  break;
  case 2017:
  text = "America had the first total solar eclipse in 99 years";
  break;
  case 2016:
  text = "Donald Trump was elected president of the United States";
  break;
  case 2015:
  text = "The U.S. Women Soccer Team wins the World Cup";
  break;
  case 2014:
  text = "The Seattle Seahawks beat the Denver Broncos, 43-8, to win their first Super Bowl in franchise history";
  break;
  case 2013:
  text = "The movie Iron Man 3 came out";
  break;
  case 2012:
  text = "The Miami Heat win their second NBA championship in franchise history";
  break;
  case 2011:
  text = "U.S. troops and CIA operatives shoot and terrorist kill Osama bin Laden in Pakistan";
  break;
  case 2010:
  text = "The United States finds more than $1 trillion in mineral resources in the mountains of Afghanistan";
  break

  default:
  text = "";
  break;
}
debugger;
document.getElementById("question").innerText = text;
debugger;

  }
</script>

<script src="script.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like great progress, if you keep up the motivation you'll be a great developer one day. It seems that you put a lot of hard work into this, but there are some tools that can help you succeed more easily.

As for the obstacles for it changing the innerHTML/innerText of the `div.question` there are a few things that will help you achieve that.

1. it seems you have the  two times (and each with a big gap. (I'd expect it to be just one time and at the bottom of the body. `<script src='/script.js'></script>`.
2. I'd recommend using a more JSON-like format for the questions rather than switch/cases: `{ 2019: "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole." }`.
3. You can then do `const promptedYearReplied = prompt('choose a year')` also in most real websites it would be `<label>Your selected Year<input id='yearOfImportance' onChange='reselectYear()' /></label>` (instead of using a prompt).
4. Also, with the JSON (object/lookup/dictionary/HashMap) you can then display the alert (or better yet box/div/card with the text using. `document.querySelector('card-with-description').innerText = eventsLookup[promptedYearReplied]`. (Where you got: `promptedYearReplied` from either prompt as before or using `document.querySelector('yearOfImportance').value`.
5. using the JSON format would make the `Number("promptedYear")` casting unnecessary because `{1929: "Something"}['1929']` would still work in JS.
6. You don't need an actual `<form>` HTML tag unless you're going to submit the form to some server. If keeping it on the frontend its a bit overkill.
7. The code hadn't closed the bracket for the `switch {` statement `}` before your code about `document.getElementById("Question")`.
8. `document.getElementById("Question")` was probably a typo because the only div similar to that has an id of `id="question"` (not uppercase).
9. In the `onclick="qTwo()"` it seemed you wanted to return false but that was not part of the `onClick=""`'s string so it didn't count.
10. I'd recommend writing all JavaScript in a code editor like VS Code, Sublime, Atom, or even Webstorm/Eclipse and getting ES Lint. Separate your files by HTML vs JS so that the linters can catch these kinds of typos and do syntax highlighting for strings.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body style="background-color:SandyBrown;">
    <script src="script.js">

    </script>
    <div id="question"></div>
    <h1 style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">
    Oh what a year that was!
    <h1>
    <p style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">
    If you are seeing this in the year 2020, you know what we all went through this year. There was everything from a gloabl pandemic, forest fires, presidental elections, everything. We all likely faced individual struggles as well. But do you were wish you could see what another year was like?<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
      
          Let's take a blast to the past</p>
        <button style="text-align:center"; onclick="qone()">Question</button>
     <script>
       function qone() {
 var text;
 var year = prompt("How was your 2020?");
 switch(year) {
  case "Great":
    text = "That makes one of us...";
    break;
  case "Bad":
    text = "That makes two of us...";
    break;
  case "No comment":
    text = "Understood";
    break;
  default:
    text = "I Understand";
  }
   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = text;
}
     </script>
        
<br>
<br>
<div style="color:DarkSlateGray;font-family:monospace;text-align:center;">

<label for=“year”>
What year do you want to go to? You can go back anywhere from 1 to 100 years ago!
</label>
<input id='selectedYear' onkeydown='qtwo()' style='text-align: center' type='text' placeholder='2010' />
<br>

<div id="qtwo"></div>



<script>
  function qtwo(e){
    var text = "";
    var userInputtedYear = document.querySelector('#selectedYear').value;
    console.log(userInputtedYear);
    const eventByYearLookup = {
      2019: "Scientists release first-ever image of black hole.",
      2018: "The United States Leaves the Iran Nuclear Deal.",
      2017: "America had the first total solar eclipse in 99 years",
      2016: "Donald Trump was elected president of the United States",
      2015: "The U.S. Women Soccer Team wins the World Cup",
      2014: "The Seattle Seahawks beat the Denver Broncos, 43-8, to win their first Super Bowl in franchise history",
      2013: "The movie Iron Man 3 came out",
      2012: "The Miami Heat win their second NBA championship in franchise history",
      2011: "U.S. troops and CIA operatives shoot and terrorist kill Osama bin Laden in Pakistan",
      2010: "The United States finds more than $1 trillion in mineral resources in the mountains of Afghanistan",
    }
    document.getElementById("question").innerText = eventByYearLookup[Math.min(userInputtedYear, 2010)] || "";
  }
</script>

<script src="script.js">

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the input that is a string to int

```
switch(parseInt(numyrs)) {
```

or change the cases for compare a string with quotation marks, like "year"

```
case "2019":
```

Comment: This is only one of the fixes necessary to make the page work.